# Android layout, resize by percentage and maintain proportion

Tags: android, layout

I have an image that I have created at a larger dimension than how it will most likely be displayed.  Let's say it's 200x200.  I'm testing on a device that is 800x480 in landscape mode.  My goal is to have this image resize to 1/4th the height of the current view, dock to the top right corner, and also maintain the aspect ratio.  This would mean when viewing at 800x480, my image would be in the top right corner displaying at 120x120.

I thought the way to do this was to use a vertical LinearLayout with a weightSum and layout_weights among the elements (using empty elements with layout_weight for padding if necessary) and adjustViewBounds=true on the ImageView, but I'm not able to get the effect I'm going for.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't even have to worry about weightSum or adjustViewBounds, I don't think. You should be on the right track, though. Try this (untested) layout, and see if it gets your result:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qtr_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This just puts an empty view below the image, weighted to take 3/4 of the screen, while the ImageView takes the remaining 1/4. You could also use `layout_gravity="right|top"` instead of `alignParentTop` and `alignParentRight`, but I just prefer it this way. Let me know if this works.

Comment: this is really close, and produces the same result as a bunch of my previous trial-and-error runs, but the only thing i'm still getting is that the ImageView is reporting back to the parent layout that it needs horizontal space equal to the original dimensions.  So, my image is resized but it's positioned wrong.  The solution was to set scaleType to fitEnd, but the layout container is still the wrong width.  Right now that doesn't have any consequence, so I could be all good.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I can see how that would happen. I'm actually thinking an actual java coded solution might end up working best for what you're trying to do. However, if the container having the wrong width isn't a problem, try adding one more attribute to your ImageView: `android:gravity="top|right"`.

Comment: Also, quick thought (and I could be horribly off base), does the order of attributes matter when inflating an XML document? I wonder if maybe placing the scaleType attribute before the layout_width and layout_height attributes could affect the measurements?

Comment: I guess actually the scaleType AND src attributes would have to move - maybe just place width and height at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

and now it is how if you will, for example, create a form and it supports the application to a phone that has a different resolution than the emulator (the labels are not aligned).
Is it possible to standardize the resolution, use "%" as the unit of measurement instead of px, ... ?